# Undefined module when using Oasis to build an OCaml project

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

It's me, again.. I am working on an `OCaml` project and I would like to use `Oasis` to build the whole code base. Here is how my codebase is organized.

```
src/
    core/
      init.ml
      type.ml
      utils.ml
    plugin/
      main.ml
```

I firstly only build the library with the following `_oasis` file:

```
Library "engine"                                                       
Path: src/core                                                         
Modules:                                                               
  Init,                                                                
  Type,                                                                
  Utils                                                            
BuildDepends:   deriving, deriving.syntax, core, batteries             
XMETADescription: core engine
```

And it works fine. There is no error and I can find a library `engine.a` in the `_build/src/core` folder.

However, when I try to include the library in the `main.ml` with the following way:

```
Module T = Engine.Type
...
```

And compile with the following `_oasis` file:

```
Library "engine"                                                       
Path: src/core                                                         
Modules:                                                               
  Init,                                                                
  Type,                                                                
  Utils                                                            
BuildDepends:   deriving, deriving.syntax, core, batteries             
XMETADescription: core engine


Executable "main"                                                      
  Path:           src/plugin                                         
  MainIs:         main.ml                                              
  CompiledObject: best                                                   
  Install:        false                                                  
  BuildDepends:   core, batteries, engine
```

I got an error:

```
Unbound module Engine
```

Am I doing anything  wrong here? Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_oasis` module defines a library with the name `engine` but it does not define an `Engine` module.  So your `Init`, `Type` and `Utils` modules are exposed and should be accessible directly without any prefix.

If you want to pack those modules into a parent you can:

- Manually pack each module into one big `engine.ml` file
- Use `Pack: true` in the `Library` section of your `_oasis` file which would pack the included modules into a module called `Engine`
- Use module aliases (see [the OCaml manual for more information](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec235))